# How to display rssi of wifi networks with SSID in a listview?

Tags: android

I'm scanning nearby wifinetworks in androidapp and want to display SSID in a textview and signal level using RSSI of the networks in a imageview. Is there a vector asset that can be used to indicate signal strength in UI?

I have obtained wifi networks using scan_results function. Using a textview, I am displaying SSID/network name of the networks. I want to display RSSI of the network in the listview as well but coudn't find a way to achieve it. I have calculated signallevel using calculatesignallevel function.

```
size=scanResults.size();
closeWaitDialog();
// showDialogMessage("result", scanResults.toString());
size = size - 1;
while (size >= 0)
{
      int signalstrength=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(scanResults.get(size).rssi(),4);
      HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
      item.put(ITEM_KEY, scanResults.get(size).ssid());
      arraylist.add(item);
      size--;
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: So your problem is that you do not get rssi from ScanResult? If yes, Which OS version are you testing?

Comment: I am getting rssi from scanresult but couldnt figure out how to bring it to listview

Comment: Make Model class to save all the wifi details related to wifi and change `HashMap<String, yourModelClass>`. Does this make sense ?

Comment: `Where do I get the widgets or drawable assets to indicate signal strength in UI` you can use your own image and ImageVIew for that.